# facebook python api add users to CustomAudience

Tags: python, facebook, api, audience

By following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api, I was able to add few users (MOBILE_ADVERTISER_ID) to a Custom Audience using cURL. However, since my goal is to do bulk loading (tens of thousands), I switched to use python SDK.

I'm getting the following error, this is the SCHEMA I've called in cUrl.

```
    audience.add_users(CustomAudience.Schema.MOBILE_ADVERTISER_ID, users)
AttributeError: type object 'Schema' has no attribute 'MOBILE_ADVERTISER_ID'
```

Here is my code

```
from facebookads.adobjects.customaudience import CustomAudience

audience = CustomAudience('custom_audience_id')
users = ['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']

audience.add_users(CustomAudience.Schema.MOBILE_ADVERTISER_ID, users)
```

Also, in cUrl I had to pass in ACCESS_TOKEN, but in Python sample code, it's not mentioned at all, how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be in small letters: `mobile_advertiser_id` instead of `MOBILE_ADVERTISER_ID`.

For the authentication:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects

my_app_id = '<APP_ID>'
my_app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
my_access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
proxies = {'http': '<HTTP_PROXY>', 'https': '<HTTPS_PROXY>'} # add proxies if needed
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token, proxies)
```

ref: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk

Comment: Thanks, now I need to look for APP_SECRET. What is the proxies?

Comment: If you have a proxy on your network, you will have to add it. Otherwise, omit it.

Comment: I will accept it now, having trouble getting to the app secert.

Comment: Just go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and click on your app, you will find the app secret directly by clicking show and putting in your Facebook account password.